# How do I arrange workspaces in Ubuntu?

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

I just installed 14.04.  I want 4 workspaces, arranged horizontally.  But when I set that up, I get 4 *double* workspaces, i.e., 8 all together.  How do I get 4 *single* workspaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is only to set the workspaces, it seems a bit overkill to install additional software. To set it from command line, you only need two commands.

Run in a terminal:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/vsize 1
```

to set the number of *rows* to one, and

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/hsize 4
```

to set the number of *columns* to four

Comment: I have tried this and compizconfig-settings-manager suggested by earthmeLon and was only able to squeeze 3 horizontal workspaces. Not Mac OS, but still better than it used to be. Thanks =)

Answer (score 5):

The best and simple answer to your question is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open Unity Tweak Tool and click on tab **Wokspace Settings** and put the switcher **ON**.

[image]

Here you can arrange your workspaces any way you like, by default it spreads on 4 squares (2x2) you can set it your way e.g: (1x4) or (4x2) etc.

Comment: Yes; worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the number of desktops and their relative locations are controlled using `ccsm` (Compiz Configuration Settings Manager).  You may need to install this program to make the adjustments required.

Once installed, you will find these settings under **General Options** > **Desktop Size**.  The specific settings you will want to adjust are *Horizontal Virtual Size* and *Vertical Virtual Size*.

It sounds like you want four horizontal, and one vertical (4x1=4).