# How to use several workspaces?

Tags: 15.04, system-settings

I was many instructions say to go Settings - Appearence. However there is not Apperence any,any where. 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I arrange workspaces in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622390/how-do-i-arrange-workspaces-in-ubuntu)

Comment: So you say the `appearence` option is missing from settings? Please provide a screen shot of settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System Settings icons missing in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: *Maybe the setting is called differently in your language?*

You can open the **System Settings** window in English by running the following command either from a **Terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) or the **Unity HUD** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>):

```
LANG=C unity-control-center
```

You should get a window like the one below.

[image: System Settings in English]

As you can see, the **Appearance** settings belong to the icon with the purple monitor. Clicking it will display you a window that should look about like the following one.

[image: Appearance Settings (Look)]

Clicking on the **Behaviour** tab will then finally take you to the options of your interest. Here you can tick **Enable workspaces**.

[image: Appearance Settings (Behaviour)]

---

#### Option 2: *The icon (and maybe more) is entirely missing*

This can happen e.g. after accidentally uninstalling some important packages, usually `gnome-*` things. If you use the **Unity Desktop Environment** (standard Ubuntu's default), you should be able to fix it with one of the following commands. Try them out one after the other in a **Terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and check which one solves it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

<sub>Adapted from: [AskUbuntu.com: System Settings icons missing in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/468235/367990)</sub>

After one of those commands fixed it, you should be able to see and use the icons as described above.

Comment: @Yarh Did this help? Or is your icon entirely missing? If it solved your question, please accept this answer by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of it. If you really liked it, you may also upvote. Otherwise please tell me and I will see how I can improve it to solve your problem.

Comment: its entirely missing

Comment: ok,  i reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and have required settings again.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a fix for entirely missing desktop icons so that I deserve your upvote! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Open the **System Settings** -> **Appearance** -> **Behavior** and check **Enable workspaces**.

If this method does not work open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
gsettings set org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core hsize 2  
gsettings set org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core vsize 2
```

Now **workspaces** should be **enabled** - if you want to **disable** them again execute :

```
gsettings set org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core hsize 1  
gsettings set org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core vsize 1
```

Comment: thats a reason i post this question -  appearance is missing